# How to choose randomly from a 2d numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a list of lists (well its really a matrix of ratings), ground_truth. I want to make 20% of the non-zero items = 0. My initial approach is:

```
ground_truth = [[0,99,98],[0,84,97], [55,0,0]]
ground_truth = np.array(ground_truth)
np.random.choice(ground_truth)
```

However this gives the error

```
ValueError: a must be 1-dimensional
```

So my solution is to flatten my matrix into a 1d array, then pick 20% of the non-zero items randomly.

```
random_digits = np.random.choice(ground_truth.flatten()[ground_truth.flatten() > 0], 
                                int(round(len(ground_truth.flatten()) * .2))) 

in: random_digits 
out: array([99, 97])
```

Now, I want to set these items to 0, and have the changes reflected in my original matrix. How can i do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
total_non_zeros = np.count_nonzero(ground_truth)

# sample 1d index
idx = np.random.choice(total_non_zeros, int(total_non_zeros * 0.2))

# subset non zero indices and set the value at corresponding indices to zero
ground_truth[tuple(map(lambda x: x[idx], np.where(ground_truth)))] = 0

ground_truth
#array([[ 0, 99, 98],
#       [ 0, 84,  0],
#       [55,  0,  0]])
```

Comment: What exactly is np.where doing? When I run `np.where(ground_truth)` I get this result:  `(array([0, 0, 1, 1, 2], dtype=int64), array([1, 2, 1, 2, 0], dtype=int64))`.  Two separate arrays of length 5. Why is that?

Comment: @Moondra It gives the row indices (the first element) and column indices (the second element) of non zero elements. [numpy.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.where.html).

Comment: How does `ground_truth[tuple(map(lambda x: x[idx], np.where(ground_truth)))] = 0
` work? my understanding: `map(lambda x: x[idx], np.where(ground_truth)))` iterates the same number of times as the length of idx. `np.where(ground_truth)` returns the positions of all the elements in ground_truth. But we have not passed any `== 0` arguments to `np.where(ground_truth)`. How did  `np.where(ground_truth)` return only the non-zero elements here?

Comment: Zero is falsy, non zero is trusy in python. `np.where` treats non zeros as true and zero as false, and so return indices of *trues/non-zero* elements.